# How do I know Mist-type programs don't have access to my keyfile and password?

Tags: mist, parity

These programs create the keyfile and I enter my password into them whenever I send a transaction. What's to stop them from sending that info somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> What's to stop them from sending that info somewhere?

Nothing, but their reputation.

For as much as we are attempting to build systems you don't need to trust, we will inevitably need to trust someone.

Answer (score 2):

Both mist and parity are open source. If there was such a backdoor, it'd have to be hidden very well, least some random security researcher just spot it.